# Removal of nested observable from stream

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a class `ObservableCollection<T>` which represents a changing collection:

```
public interface IObservableCollection<T> : IObservable<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    void Add(T item);
    void Remove(T item);
}
```

When an item is added or removed, internally a `Subject<IEnumerable<T>>` has its `OnNext` method called with the new `IEnumerable<T>` which is exposed through the `Subscribe` method of `IObservableCollection<T>`.

I also have a class `Person`:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; }
    IObservable<int> Position { get; }
}
```

What I want to do is to produce a stream of `IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>>` representing each person's position, where a person is in the collection. This seems relatively straightforward:

```
var peopleCollectionStream = new ObservableCollection<IPerson>();

var peoplePositions = from people in peopleCollectionStream
                      from updateList in
                          (from person in people
                           select person.Position.Select(pos => Tuple.Create(person.Name, pos)))
                           .CombineLatest()
                      select updateList;
```

I can now subscribe to the stream like so:

```
peoplePositions
    .Subscribe(people =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something was updated");
        foreach (var personTuple in people)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", personTuple.Item1, personTuple.Item2);
    });
```

And I get the desired output:

```
var alice = new Person() { Name = "Alice" };
peopleCollectionStream.Add(alice);        // Alice -> 0
alice.Move(2);                            // Alice -> 2
var bob = new Person() { Name = "Bob" };
peopleCollectionStream.Add(bob);          // Alice -> 2, Bob -> 0
bob.Move(3);                              // Alice -> 2, Bob -> 3
```

The problem arises when I wish to remove a person from the collection, and therefore exclude their updates from the stream:

```
peopleCollectionStream.Remove(bob);       // Alice -> 2
bob.Move(4);                              // Alice -> 2, Bob -> 4
```

I want to stop Bob's position updates from being included if he was removed from the collection. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that trying to work with Add and Remove events is a bad idea, if you want to do these sorts of functional things. Matching up the removes with the adds, and making sure underlying code does it too, is a lot of work.

What I do instead is use perishable items / collections. I pair each item with a lifetime (cancellation token), and the item is considered removed when its lifetime ends. Then I use those lifetimes when wiring up other things. I use a collection type, called `PerishableCollection<T>`, which takes items paired with lifetimes and allows you to watch its contents as an `IObservable<Perishable<T>>`.

I [wrote a blog post about perishable collections](http://twistedoakstudios.com/blog/Post1941_perishable-collections-the-benefits-of-removal-by-lifetime), and published a [nuget library you can reference](http://nuget.org/packages/TwistedOak.Collections.PerishableCollection/).

Here's code that should flatten a perishable collection of perishable collections:

```
public static PerishableCollection<T> Flattened<T>(this PerishableCollection<PerishableCollection<T>> collectionOfCollections, Lifetime lifetimeOfResult) {
    if (collectionOfCollections == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("collectionOfCollections");

    var flattenedCollection = new PerishableCollection<T>();
    collectionOfCollections.CurrentAndFutureItems().Subscribe(
        c => c.Value.CurrentAndFutureItems().Subscribe(

            // OnItem: include in result, but prevent lifetimes from exceeding source's lifetime
            e => flattenedCollection.Add(
                item: e.Value,
                lifetime: e.Lifetime.Min(c.Lifetime)),

            // subscription to c ends when the c's lifetime ends or result is no longer needed
            c.Lifetime.Min(lifetimeOfResult)),

        // subscription ends when result is no longer needed
        lifetimeOfResult);

    return flattenedCollection;
}
```

The above works by subscribing to receive collections added to the collection of collections, then for each of those subscribing to receive items. The items are placed into the resulting collection, with a lifetime that ends when either the item dies or its collection dies. All the subscriptions die when the lifetime given to the method dies.

Another way to approach this problem is to write a method to flatten an `IObservable<Perishable<IObservable<Perishable<T>>>>`. That would have the benefit of not requiring the caller to manage the lifetime of the result so explicitly and being applicable in more situations. However, that method is a lot harder to write because you must deal with sequences failing/completing in a thread-safe way.

Here's an example of using the flatten method (make a new console application, reference perishable collections, paste in the above method and also this one):

```
using TwistedOak.Collections;
using TwistedOak.Util;

static void Main() {
    var p = new PerishableCollection<PerishableCollection<string>>();
    var f = p.Flattened(Lifetime.Immortal);
    f.CurrentAndFutureItems().Subscribe(e => {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} added to flattened", e.Value);
        e.Lifetime.WhenDead(() => Console.WriteLine("{0} removed from flattened", e.Value));
    });

    // add some 'c' items to f via p
    var c = new PerishableCollection<string>();
    var cLife = new LifetimeSource();
    c.Add("candy", Lifetime.Immortal);
    p.Add(c, cLife.Lifetime);
    c.Add("cane", Lifetime.Immortal);

    // add some 'd' items to f via p
    var d = new PerishableCollection<string>();
    p.Add(d, Lifetime.Immortal);
    d.Add("door", Lifetime.Immortal);
    d.Add("dock", Lifetime.Immortal);


    // should remove c's items from f via removing c from p
    cLife.EndLifetime();
}
```

The code should output:

```
candy added to flattened
cane added to flattened
door added to flattened
dock added to flattened
candy removed from flattened
cane removed from flattened
```

Hopefully that's enough to get you started down an easier path.

Comment: This is a really interesting concept, thank you - I'll have to study it further to see if it is applicable in my situation. Nice blog too

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the `.Switch` operator. By selecting only the most recent list of observables to subscribe to, the stream excludes any that are not present in the newest version of the collection:

```
var peoplePositions = (from people in peopleCollectionStream
                       select
                           (from person in people
                            select person.Position
                                .Select(pos => Tuple.Create(person.Name, pos))
                            ).CombineLatest()
                       ).Switch();
```

(Incidentally, if anyone has any good recommendations on formatting when using bracketed/nested linq query syntax please let me know because the above looks quite awful!)

Comment: Commenting on your request for recommendations. Two things: 1) I would use the from... from syntax (for SelectMany) rather than the innermost .Select. Second, when the nesting gets too complex, consider refactoring it out into a separate method. This gets hard if you use anonymous types, but you appear to be safe in this example at least.

Comment: Thanks, solid advice. I don't often use query syntax but I do find it easier to write when nesting. In my demo project I was actually using anonymous types but in a real scenario I'll definitely split up these chunks into methods and use a dedicated structure.